# How to treat a poor question with a good answer?

Tags: discussion

Regarding [I done what the web said to do and still get this error msg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88371/i-done-what-the-web-said-to-do-and-still-get-this-error-msg) the question is poor enough that it is at -2 (though good enough I found it by searching for my error message). But the one non-up voted answer resolved my own question. What's the proper way to deal with this?

Should I edit the question to be more generic and informational? Just up vote the good answer? Or write my own question (judging from the user profile, they probably won't come back and accept the good answer)?

Answer (score 4):

If the solution worked, then I would strongly recommend you upvote it - questions who have answers with at least one upvote are considered "answered" by the system. By upvoting that answer you add it to the list of questions with answers (even though it may never be "accepted" as the answer). If the question and answer need some editing to help make them more clear, doing that as well will only help people coming to that question in the future. You're right in saying that question needs a bit of help, since you've had the same issue editing to include more details and better formatting will only help other people find it from search engines.